# How to apply constraints to limb movements of a 3D human model?

Tags: quaternion, skeletal-animation, joints, inverse-kinematics, euler-angles

I'm animating a 3D human model using playcanvas game engine according to the quaternion data provided by IMU sensors. How can I limit the movements of the limbs of the human model to avoid unrealistic postures? Is there a mathematical method to limit joint angels?

Comment: [related](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bKHBzRsL49A)

Comment: I just mentioned about [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jfpgj-9EaP8)